# Redireccion de cgi-bin en .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

En mi proyecto tengo unas urls con el siguiente formato

```
xxx/cgi-bin/index.pl/c/10/yyy/
```

donde, `xxx` es la direccion web.

Me gustaría que en dichas urls no apareciera la ruta `cgi-bin/index.pl`.

He estado probando diferentes configuraciones del .htaccess, pero no he conseguido eliminar dicha parte, quedando `xxx/c/10`.

Edit:

A petición de Mariano, comento que tanto los css, como archivos js, imágenes... los tengo fuera de la ruta de /cgi-bin, en otra carpeta /html.

No tengo ni idea de como poder indicar que esto cuelga de otro directorio y que la url me redirija la parte de scripts perl a la ruta sin /cgi-bin/index.pl...

Comment: No habría ninguna excepción. Es decir, **todas** las solicitudes a tu web irían a leer de la carpeta `cgi-bin/index.pl`?? O sólo las que son a `c/10`?? Ahí está todo? También las imágenes? No hay nada fuera de esa carpeta?

Comment: No, fuera de cgi-bin tambien tengo otras carpetas a las que accedo.

Comment: Entonces, ¿Cómo hacemos para diferenciar que cuando se acceda a una URL, Apache lo busque en `cgi-bin/index.pl` o que lo busque fuera de `cgi-bin`?

Comment: Prueba a usar en la configuración de Apache un "reverse proxy" para la url

Answer (score 0):

> No tengo ni idea de como poder indicar que esto cuelga de otro directorio y que la url me redirija la parte de scripts perl a la ruta sin /cgi-bin/index.pl

Si no tenés idea, menos quien quiera responderte. Se tiene que definir ***algo*** para que Apache pueda definir hacia dónde reescribir.

Se me ocurren 2 formas:

**1. Reescribir si no tiene una extensión de css/html/js/etc**

Una opción, que no sé si te sirve, pero supongo que es la más viable en este caso, es reescribir dependiendo de la extensión del archivo. De esta forma, generamos excepciones para cada extensión que quieras que busque fuera de `/cgi-bin/index.pl`.

```python
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#Si no termina con estas extensiones
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:html?|css|png|jpe?g|gif)$ [NC]
#Reescribir
RewriteRule (.+) cgi-bin/index.pl/$1 [L]
```

A lo que le deberías completar la lista de extensiones de archivos que no tiene que reescribir.

**2. Poner excepciones a carpetas específicas**

O podemos reescribir, siempre que no intente acceder a alguna de las carpetas que te interese poner como excepción.

```python
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#Si no empieza con alguna de estas carpetas:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(?:img|images|scripts|proyecto|bla|etc)(?:/|$) [NC]
#Reescribir
RewriteRule (.*) cgi-bin/index.pl/$1 [L]
```

---

Otras opciones podrían ser:

- Reescribir a `cgi-bin/index.pl/` si la URL a la que se accede no existe.
- La opción **2** pero al revés, reescribir sólo si es a una lista de carpetas dentro de `cgi-bin/index.pl/` predefinidas.
- Reescribir sólo si existe el archivo en `cgi-bin/index.pl/`.
- Reescribir sólo si se intenta acceder a un recurso terminado en `.pl`.
- Abrir otro puerto aparte del 80, y no reescribir en ese puerto, entonces accederías a tus imagenes como `http://tusitio.ext:1234/tu-script.js` (con el problema de que lo considere otro dominio).

... en fin, alguna regla tiene que cumplirse para diferenciarlo, pero vos sos el programador, y definir eso es tarea tuya.